# How can I detect graphic server presence?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I am developing a small console application with graphic capabilities.
I want to run this application on a remote windows session without graphic.
How can my application discover that it needs to run in console mode?

Comment: What OS? What means of displaying graphics (e.g. X-Windows?)

Comment: I will run the application on a remote windows session. on unix I just check getenv("DISPLAY")

Comment: OK - have added a tag

Comment: i'd just add a flag `--nographics`, or `--console`, to make it run in text-only mode.  The thing is that most remote windows access need graphics capabilities, so it's hard for your program to guess the users intention.